# I have created multiple JSP pages and I want to call each of them one after another

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

Basically I have made a simulation of a football match in my JSP file using Servlet code. Each JSP file is simulation of one match. So basically these files are supposed to be running in background one after another so my database keeps getting updated after an interval of time. I want a main java/html/jsp file that calls them one by one after an interval of time.
Please share any ideas if you have any.
I am new to this.

Comment: Perhaps you could share what already have in terms of code? You basically need one JSP that acts as a controller and loops through each subpage waiting for a response. Depending on how quick each one of this matches is you may want to tweak your server's response timeout it the entire thing takes too long.

Comment: The code is too long to be shared. If there is any other way I can share the code with you please tell me. Also, can you give me an example to call subpages from a main JSP file?

Comment: JSP pages as background processes is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer for this would be that you shouldn't use JSPs for running a background task.

A JSP is a user interface component and should be used as such.

If you need to do such a task you can write it all in a servlet and initialize it at start up. The tasks will then keep running in the background.

Use the `init` method if the servlets and write your logic of the background tasks.

Set up annotations or web.xml for initializing the servlets on start up.

The web container will take care if initializing the servlets by invoking the `init` method of each servlet one by one.

You can also specify the order in which the servlets are initialized.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Initially I did the same. But I have no clue how to call multiple servlet pages one after another. The main purpose of doing this is that I want to simulate a whole tournament, and each servlet contains simulation of a match. So I want to update my database in that order. If there is any way that I can solve this issue then please give suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to "call" the servlets. You just have to set them up using annotations or in web.xml and start up your web app. The web container will take care if starting up the servlets and running any background process. You don't need to map these servlets with URL mappings.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you. Thank you!